# 'Mutating method sent to immutable object error' in Xcode

Tags: arrays, object, methods, mutable

I am unsure why I get this error when I run my program a certain way.

```
2014-05-15 16:19:28.932 Puzzle[1002:f803] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> -[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

I have an NSMutableArray called 'levelsCompleteArray' that I am trying to cycle through to see when the first NO, (or 0) appears and to set that iteration to a variable called 'picIndex'. If there are no YES's in the array, then the program works fine. When there is one in the next iteration, however, I get the message posted above. Does anyone know why? Code below:

```
[levelsCompleteArray replaceObjectAtIndex:picIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

BOOL wonLevel=NO;

int i=picIndex;

while (wonLevel==NO)
{
    BOOL status =[[levelsCompleteArray objectAtIndex:i] boolValue];
    if (status==1) 
    {
        i=i+1;
        if(i==3)
        {
            picIndex=0;
            wonLevel=YES;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        picIndex=i;
        wonLevel=YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess what. `levelsCompleteArray` is immutable. And while we're at it, purge that `xcode` tag. It's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like levelsCompleteArray is an NSArray which is immutatable. To turn it into a mutable array try this:

```
NSMutableArray* mutableLevelsCompleteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:levelsCompleteArray];
```

Comment: I'll try that now. levelsCompleteArray is declared as such though: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *levelsCompleteArray; I believe something in my code is changing it to be immutable.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I'm still unsure why it changed to a immutable array but I'll dig into that more.